# How to read child nodes from XML without knowing their names using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I apologize if this was asked before. (I'm just learning this.)

Say, I have the following XML:

```
<Row>
<c0>1</c0>
<c1>31b64f1cb075</c1>
<c2>Developer</c2>
<c3/>
<c4/>
<c5/>
<c6/>
<c7/>
<c8>USA</c8>
<c9>http://www.microsoft.com</c9>
<c10>sales@microsoft.com</c10>
<c11/>
<c12/>
<c13/>
<c14>-2147483648</c14>
<c15>2012-03-08T09:55:42-08:00</c15>
<c16>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</c16>
<c17>587312C</c17>
</Row>
```

Say, I get to the "row" element by using:

```
//xmlReader is of type XmlReader
xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Row");
```

But how do I collect all "c*" child elements not knowing their names and how many of them are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use an XmlDocument to load your xml and simply loop through the childnodes like this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("yourxml");

XmlNode root = doc.FirstChild;

//Display the contents of the child nodes.
if (root.HasChildNodes)
{
  for (int i=0; i<root.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(root.ChildNodes[i].InnerText);
  }
}
```

You can read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq to XML you could just use `Elements()` to get all the direct children (or use `Descendants` for any descendant):

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("test.xml"); //contains your xml
foreach (var child in root.Elements())
{
    Console.WriteLine(child.Name);
}
```

Comment: I never used Linq before and it would take longer for me to learn it. Is there any way to do it without it?

Comment: There are multiple ways of accessing and manipulating XML, they are similar and worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();//xml doc used for xml parsing
                xdoc.Load(@"test.xml");//loading XML in xml doc

                if (xdoc.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    XmlNodeList xm = xdoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;

                    // In this loop you have get all the child control 
                    foreach (XmlNode x in xm) 
                    {

                       string data=  x.InnerXml;

                    }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var xml="<Row>...</Row>"
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
        if (xmlReader.ReadToFollowing("Row"))
        {
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    var name = xmlReader.Name;
                    //read value of element.
                    while (xmlReader.Read())
                    {                            
                        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace)
                            break;
                        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                        {
                            var value = xmlReader.Value;
                        }
                        else if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this code can worked.